# Magento 2 over ride page builder CSS with custom theme

Tags: php, css, magento, less, magento2

We are upgrading our Magento from 2.2.9 to Magento 2.3.2 which includes page builder. We are using a custom theme which includes our less files. Magento added a new class into the 'page builder' ('page builder' is a module - wysiwyg used in magento backend for cms work) 
CSS styles which now has broken our current custom style. 
The new Magento code added is

```
a.button {
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

this file is:
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/web/css/source/content-type/slider/_default.less

However this addition of styling has broken my existing buttons on my theme.

I have added a new less file at
app/design/frontend/{CompanyName}/site/web/css/source/{ThemeName}/_pagebuilder.less
which is referenced by my themes _extend.less file

My new less file is compiling, and it is added into the stack. 
My less looks like this:

```
a.button{
  padding: 0 39px !important;
  -webkit-appearance: button !important; 
}
```

Notice that I do not have the style:

```
 color: inherit;
```

This bit of style is breaking my existing buttons.

I was expecting that the Magento 2 style would simply not render since I added my custom less into the theme _extend.less file, However both my theme style and the Magento style is rendering in the browser. 
I was expecting only my custom style to render and not both my style and the Magento style.

Comment: whos stylesheet comes first? remember the first C is cascading

Comment: Good point. The Magento stylesheet comes first. I want to omit the tag 'color: inherit;' but Magento inserts this

Comment: I think you have to create folder like this Magezon_PageBuilder/view/frontend/web/css/source/content-type/slider/_default.less in your theme then you can over ride it

Comment: did you add  `color ` into your own less?